# C-languge: Creating a generic function out of two similiar functions which have different return values

Tags: c, function, embedded, generic-programming, misra

I am writing two different functions with two different parameter data types. Additionally, both of the functions have different return types. The first function `Function_One_u4` has two parameters of type `uint8`: `signal_one_u4` and `signal_two_u4`. On the other hand, function `Function_Two_u16` has similiar pattern, but two signals are of type `uint16`: `signal_one_u16` and `signal_two_u16`. Thus, first and second functions have return type `uint8` and `uint16`, respectively. Additionally, both functions return different ERROR values in the `default` statements.

```
uint8 Function_One_u4(const uint8 mode_u2,
                      const uint8 signal_one_u4,
                      const uint8 signal_two_u4)
{
    switch(mode_u2)
    {
        case NOT_ACTIVE_U2:
        {
            return signal_two_u4;
        }
        case ACTIVE_U2:
        {
            return signal_one_u4;
        }
        case ERROR_U2:
        {
            return signal_one_u4;
        }
        case NOT_AVLB_U2:
        {
            return signal_two_u4;
        }
        default:
        {

            return ERROR_U4; /* Return value of 15 */
        }
    }
}

uint16 Function_Two_u16(const uint8 mode_u2,
                        const uint8 signal_one_u16,
                        const uint8 signal_two_u16)
{
    switch(mode_u2)
    {
        case NOT_ACTIVE_U2:
        {
            return signal_two_u16;
        }
        case ACTIVE_U2:
        {
            return signal_one_u16;
        }
        case ERROR_U2:
        {
            return signal_one_u16;
        }
        case NOT_AVLB_U2:
        {
            return signal_two_u16;
        }
        default:
        {

            return ERROR_U16; /* Return value of 65535 */
        }
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    uint8  ret_val_u4  = Function_One_u4();
    uint16 ret_val_u16 = Function_Two_u16();
}
```

You can notice that functions pretty much have the same logic - based on the parameter `uint8 mode_u2`, they return either first or second signal. Therefore, it makes sense to make a generic function with the help of *templates*. The generic function would avoid duplicating the `switch case` code:

```
<T> Generic_Function_<T> (const uint8 mode_u2,
                          const <T> signal_one,
                          const <T> signal_two,
                          const <T> error)
{
    switch(mode_u2)
    {
        case NOT_ACTIVE_<T>:
        {
            return signal_two;
        }
        case ACTIVE_<T>:
        {
            return signal_one;
        }
        case ERROR_<T>:
        {
            return signal_one;
        }
        case NOT_AVLB_<T>:
        {
            return signal_two;
        }
        default:
        {
            return error;
        }
    }
}

uint8 Function_One_u4(const uint8 mode_u2,
                      const uint8 signal_one_u4,
                      const uint8 signal_two_u4)
{
    Generic_Function_<T>(mode_u2, signal_one_u4, signal_two_u4);
}

uint16 Function_Two_u16(const uint8 mode_u2,
                        const uint8 signal_one_u16,
                        const uint8 signal_two_u16)
{
    Generic_Function_<T>(mode_u2, signal_one_u16, signal_two_u16);
}
```

However, C language does not support templates. I have found online that one can create C templates using preprocessor macros. But I also read that using macros for functions should be avoided as they increase a chance of introducing errors in your code.
I am writing a safety-critical MISRA Software in C language, so unexpected errors sneaking in the code would not be something very nice :).

Is there some other suggestion on how to handle the code duplication?
Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, programmers have a tendency to get too extreme in their attempts to avoid code repetition. It should be avoided when possible, sure, but not at any cost. In the context of safety-critical systems, generic programming is to be avoided:

First, you must at least in theory be able to prove that all execution paths are actually executed - code coverage. Generic programming can add false safety here, if you merge 2 functions into one then that function does get executed, but only for one of the use-cases.

Second, safety-critical system must be 100% deterministic with no unknown parameters. So traditionally generic programming doesn't make a lot of sense to begin with. You should ideally be able to trace every requirement in the specification to a certain chunk of code and then design a test for that code. This part gets a whole lot easier with specialized functions instead of generic ones.

---

There are tricks with macros or C11 `_Generic` (banned by MISRA-C) that could be used here, but I think this specific case could be simplified without making things too complicated. Why not simply add an additional parameter for "U type"? I see no obvious reason why the functions can't be rewritten like this:

```
uint16_t function (uint8_t mode
                   uint8_t singal_one,
                   uint8_t signal_two
                   utype_t utype)
{
  uint16_t result;

  switch(mode)
  {
    case NOT_ACTIVE: { result = signal_two; break; }
    case ACTIVE:     { result = signal_one; break; }
    case ERROR:      { result = signal_one; break; }
    case NOT_AVLB:   { result = signal_two; break; }
    default:         
    { 
      if(utype==U2)
      {
        result = (uint16_t) ERROR_U2;
      }
      else
      {
        result = ERROR_U4;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}
```

I removed the `const` from the parameters since that part is just subjective coding style unrelated to safety.

Notes from a MISRA-C context:

- I switched to the recommended types from stdint.h instead of homebrewed ones.
- The conversion from `uint8_t` to `uint16_t` is fine in MISRA-C, they are of the same essential type category. You just have to dodge the silly rule about composite expressions getting assigned to a wider type, hence the convoluted default above,  which assumes `ERROR_U2` is 8 bits but `ERROR_U4` is 16 bits.
- Multiple return statements aren't allowed. Which is sometimes a bad rule, sometimes it makes perfect sense. In this case you can simply conform by using a result variable and a single return, without affecting readability.

I didn't run this code in static analysis but I think it's MISRA-C compliant.

Just for reference, the macro alternative, which questionable both in general and from a MISRA-C point-of-view, would go like this:

```
#define function(n) uint16_t function_##n (uint8_t mode_u2, ...
   ...
  default: { result = ERROR_##n;
```

And then you can have this macro generating 2 different functions with `function(U2)` and `function(U4)` and let the macro expand the contents of the function to different enums etc. Doesn't solve the return type though, so you might have to do as in my first example still.

Comment: I was actually thinking of passing a 'flag' variable - in your case `utype_t utype` - before. However, I have ever read in the book _Code Complete_ by Steve McConnell that such practice is bad. And in such cases, one should better create two separate routines. But that is a very general statement, and in this case, it might make sense to do it. I am still trying to find his original statement for this argument. And regarding the _Multiple return statements aren't allowed_, I do not generally agree with this rule. In my case, they make the code more readble and easier to follow.

Comment: The OP showed that the first function returned `uint8` and assigned it to a `uint8`. I don't see how returning `uint16` and then assigning it to a `uint8` is anything but confusing and the use of the flag is error prone.

Comment: @fdk1342 Because you can merge 2 functions into 1 this way. Why is using an additional enum more error prone than the enum the OP already used? How would you have written this in a MISRA-C compliant way then?

Comment: @Lundin The new function doesn't meet the criteria stated in the question.  The `mode` parameter would come from a variable that is passed.  The `utype` is supposed to be a constant but instead of just choosing the correct function based on the input types you have to think about if you want a 8 bit or 16 bit error value.  It is prone to cut / paste errors and having to think about it is a waste of time.  The return value is also a problem for MISRA-C (and just the general warning you would get) when casting from u16 to u8.  You'll have to document the deviation for every call of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You have it all covered. You can write a macro that generates the function for you or you can duplicate the logic for the new types. C11 encourages the use of macros for generic programming via the `_Generic` [preprocessor directive](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic).

`_Generic` is forbidden by MISRA, as are function-like macros. So under MISRA you'll need to use both functions.

Comment: MISRA C doesn't allow C11. `_Generic` was introduced with C11

Comment: @ nickelpro So are you suggesting then to leave the code as it currently is, i.e. with two seperate functions?

Comment: @Simple Switch to C++ if you want a better template experience. Come to the dark side ;)

Comment: @SimpleThings Yes, it's your only option under MISRA C

Comment: @＿Static＿assert C11 Is available under MISRA C:2012 Amendment 2

Comment: @nick could you show some reference for that? Wikipedia says *"MISRA C:2012 extends support to the C99 version of the C language (while maintaining guidelines for C90), in addition to including a number of improvements that can reduce the cost and complexity of compliance, whilst aiding consistent, safe use of C in critical systems."*

Comment: @＿Static＿assert https://www.misra.org.uk/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=42UepuUAjQ4%3d&tabid=57

MISRA 2012 is being updated in a series of amendments. Amendment 2 addresses most of C11, including _Generic, atomics, and threading. It also updates all of the C99 language to read "C99 and later." To directly answer your question, section 1.2 of the amendment: "1. ISO/IEC 9899:2011 is now supported by MISRA C:2012."

Comment: @nickelpro I would love if my department were using C++, but unforunately that is not the case. We are using C language, probably because of all the legacy code that is developed over 15 years. Moreover, other teams (80% of the people) which are doing application software, are using Simulink. So for them the target language does not play any role :). Thus, I would like to hear C-related solutions.

Comment: @SimpleThings Amendment 2 was released fairly recently, just couple of months ago iirc. Basically it covers C11 by banning everything that is C11...

Comment: @Lundin - Given most of the new features are so poorly standardised, that's not a bad starting point :-)

Comment: @Andrew C17 fixed a few things though, like `_Generic`. It can be used to greatly increase safety of function-like macros, so it seems strange to ban it. Even under C11, `_Generic` is still a good thing to increase program safety - it's not like it can make function-like macros less safe.

Comment: It's only banned until we sort out some Rules for the odd bits :-)

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use only Function_Two_u16 function everywhere with error value as 3rd argument as shown below.

```
uint16 Function_Two_u16(const uint8 mode_u2,
                            const uint16 signal_one_u16,
                            const uint16 signal_two_u16, const uint16 error)
```

This Function_Two_u16 works well for uint8 values also.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement the logic once and call the other functions as needed.

```
uint16 Function_Two_u16(const uint8  mode_u2,
                        const uint16 signal_one_u16,
                        const uint16 signal_two_u16)
{
    switch(mode_u2)
    {
        case NOT_ACTIVE_U2:
        {
            return signal_two_u16;
        }
        case ACTIVE_U2:
        {
            return signal_one_u16;
        }
        case ERROR_U2:
        {
            return signal_one_u16;
        }
        case NOT_AVLB_U2:
        {
            return signal_two_u16;
        }
        default:
        {

            return ERROR_U16; /* Return value of 65535 */
        }
    }
}

uint8 Function_One_u4(const uint8 mode_u2,
                      const uint8 signal_one_u4,
                      const uint8 signal_two_u4)
{
    uint8 ret = ERROR_U4;
    uint16 val = Function_Two_u16(mode_u2, signal_one_u4, signal_two_u4);
    if (val != ERROR_U16)
    {
        ret = (uint8)val;
    }
    return ret;
}
```